# How should I clean a DVD?

Tags: dvd, cleaning

What's the best way to clean a DVD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having tried everything else, I could restore a DVD to a working state with Brasso metal polish.

You apply it in circles from the center of the DVD to the edges and let it rest for a few minutes. After a while remove with a soft cloth and most scratches should be gone.
 [image]

Comment: Brasso? in circles? really?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I'm not 100% clear with what I mean to express (please mind my english, it is not my mother tongue) This post might have a better explanation http://lifehacker.com/285973/remove-scratches-from-cds-and-dvds

Answer (score 5):

It may sound crazy, but you can [clean and remove minor scratches with a banana](http://lifehacker.com/289578/clean-a-scratched-cd-or-dvd-with-a-banana). I've used this technique, and it does work.

Answer (score 3):

You can get special fluids for this and a whole host of items to do the job, but in reality a t-shirt has served me well for years :)

as a small aside, clean it inwards to outwards, not in circles as it would grind any debris in the directions of the tracks.

[image: Dos and don'ts]

... fixing scratches is anouther issue completely.

Answer (score 2):

Dip a soft cloth in Isopropyl Alcohol/Ethanol/Methanol and gently wipe the surface.Always wipe the disc surface in a non-radial back-and-forth motion (from the center hole to the outer edge).

Comment: You say non-radial, but then you say to go from the center hole to the outer edge. What do you mean by this?

Comment: Wipe the disc in a back-and-forth motion, in a linear fashion.....don't wipe it in a circular manner. Hope u got it !

Comment: I thought Alcohol/Ethanol/Methanol are corrosive when applied to plastic?